# 32-bit increment on a 16-bit system

Tags: c

Which of the 2 code parts will execute faster on a 16-bit machine?

1:

```
uint16_t inc = 1;
uint32_t sum = 0;

inc++; // 16 bit increment
sum += (uint32_t)inc; // inc has to be cast
```

2:

```
uint32_t inc = 1;
uint32_t sum = 0;

inc++; // 32 bit increment
sum += inc; // no cast for inc
```

Comment: You should profile it.

Comment: Generally speaking on a given architecture working in the native word size is fastest, so in this case I'd go with 16-bit for a 16-bit machine. That said it can depend, so I'd have a closer look at whatever architecture you're compiling for. Also it's best to avoid prematurely optimizing.

Comment: If all input values are known, the compiler should be able to optimize away any runtime calculations in both cases ...

Comment: Both of them do the same thing and the compiler is usually not stupid (with optimizations turned on)

Comment: It will depend on how both variables are used in the rest of the code.

Comment: Any half-decent compiler will optimize this example into `uint32_t sum = 2;` regardless of CPU target.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. The question is clear and does not lack clarity. And not a single comment on the question that explains what clarity is lacking. I may sound blunt, but this is a typical example of elitist gatekeeping that kreeps into StackOverlfow recently. If you truly believe that the question is unclear, then at least provide a hint of what and why.

Comment: @ChristianHujer Plenty of comments pointed out the problems before it was closed. The question is unclear because it is too broad and lacks a [mcve]. This here is pseudo code. As you already noticed, you and I read the question differently - I read it as "these are local scope variables", you read it as "these are file scope variables". Furthermore I believe the question is far too broad without a specific target in mind. Some 16 bitters are 16/32 hybrids (like the 68k families), others are rather 8/16 bit hybrids (like the HC12 families).

Comment: Also please note that "closed" is not a permanent state, this could easily get edited into shape by providing a clearer example and a specific 16 bit target.

Comment: @Lundin code shows the idea. It is easy to create code which will not be optimized. https://godbolt.org/z/jGYG6jjY7

Comment: @0___________ The whole point of trying to get something to execute faster is to make as much of it optimized as possible, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a lot on the particular 16 Bit machine, as well as the compiler's optimizer.

To simulate the behavior that really matters in a program, I have put the code inside a function operating on global variables.

Variant 1 (`uint16_t inc`):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t inc = 1;
uint32_t sum = 0;

void f() {
    inc++;
    sum += inc;
}
```

Variant 2 (`uint32_t inc`):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t inc = 1;
uint32_t sum = 0;

void f() {
    inc++;
    sum += inc;
}
```

Without any storage-class specifiers, code with the variables declared locally and nothing else actually has no observable behavior and could be optimized away entirely. So, it's important for reproducing this example to have the variables globally (or by other means produce an observable side-effect on both, `inc` and `sum`).

## Motorola 68000

Let's take the Motorola 68000 as an example.

On a Motorola 68000 (not even 68020), which is a 16/32 Bit machine, the disassembly of a function with above code and global variables decompiles to (produced with `m68k-linux-gnu-gcc-12 -O2`):

Variant 1 (`uint16_t inc`):

```
00000000 <f>:
   0:   3039 0000 0000  movew 0 <f>,%d0
   6:   5240            addqw #1,%d0
   8:   33c0 0000 0000  movew %d0,0 <f>
   e:   0280 0000 ffff  andil #65535,%d0
  14:   d1b9 0000 0000  addl %d0,0 <f>
  1a:   4e75            rts
```

Variant 2 (`uint32_t inc`):

```
00000000 <f>:
   0:   2039 0000 0000  movel 0 <f>,%d0
   6:   5280            addql #1,%d0
   8:   23c0 0000 0000  movel %d0,0 <f>
   e:   d1b9 0000 0000  addl %d0,0 <f>
  14:   4e75            rts
```

Note the additional `andil #65535,%d0` instruction to perform the upcast from d0 before adding it. However, we also need to take into account the number of cycles required for load and store. `movem` is faster than `movel`. So, without going into actual cycle counting using the 68000 user manual, we can say that on the 68000, the `uint32_t` variant of this piece of code is faster, as it requires 3 fewer bus cycles (no `andil #65535,%d0` to execute) but 2 more bus cycles (twice `movel` from/to memory instead of `movew`), so in total it requires 1 fewer bus cycle.

However, that is 1 CPU architecture/family plus compiler, and one situation of types, a totally insufficient sample size for extrapolating a generic statement.

For example, the game already changes when the compiler/optimizer could replace `andil #65535,%d0` with `extl %d0` when the types are changed from unsigned to signed.

## Intel 8086

On an Intel 8086, using *Bruce's C Compiler* (bcc), the picture is very different.
The disassembly, produced with `bcc -O -0 -S`, is as follows.

Variant 1 (`uint16_t inc`):

```
.text
export  _f
_f:
push    bp
mov     bp,sp
inc     word ptr [_inc]
mov     ax,[_inc]
mov     bx,dx
mov     di,#_sum
call    laddul
mov     [_sum],ax
mov     [_sum+2],bx
pop     bp
ret
```

Variant 2 (`uint32_t inc`):

```
.text
export  _f
_f:
push    bp
mov     bp,sp
mov     ax,[_inc]
mov     si,[_inc+2]
mov     bx,#_inc
call    lincl
mov     ax,[_sum]
mov     bx,[_sum+2]
mov     di,#_inc
call    laddul
mov     [_sum],ax
mov     [_sum+2],bx
pop     bp
ret
```

We can see that on an Intel 8086, another 16-Bit CPU, there's a huge difference between using `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` for `inc`. On an 8086, using `uint16_t` can safely be assumed to be much faster than `uint32_t`. The 32-Bit variant needs significantly more instructions and even makes calls to off-screen subroutines to perform 32-Bit operations like inc and add.

## Another Caveat

The above analysis is based on instruction count or bus fetch count. Additional cycles used by the CPU is not taken into account. But for a real-world scenario, that matters. A profiler should be used.

## Conclusion

This is very much CPU-dependent. A generic statement about all 16 Bit platforms is not possible. It largely depends on how well the 16 Bit platform in question deals with 32-Bit operands. 16-Bit CPUs that have strong support for 32-Bit operands, like Motorola 68000, will perform slightly better on `uint32_t` than `uint16_t` in this example. Whereas 16-Bit CPUs that have no support for 32-Bit operands whatsoever, like 8086, perform very poorly in the `uint32_t` case and will be much better in the `uint16_t` case.

To some extent, it also depends on the compiler, although, we might want to assume in good faith, that an optimization level like GCC's `-O2` will produce the optimum machine code for a given function at least in the case of small functions.

Overall, I would first optimize for clarity and declare data in the size that it has "by nature". Second, I would optimize for convenience and make sure that data that is passed around is passed around in a way convenient for developers. Third, I would profile if there are any performance or footprint issues, and if so, where they are, and only then optimize code, with the help of a profiler and the disassembly.

Comment: And now what happens if you enable optimizations? See for example a crappy 8 bit AVR compiler https://godbolt.org/z/84fWT3qv8. It easily outperforms your 68000 examples because it was compiled in a way relevant to a performance discussion.

Comment: @Lundin the example for Motorola 68000 was compiled with -O2. There is nothing left that could be optimized. The optimizer has already optimized `addl #1,d0` (6 bytes) to `addql #1,d0` (2 bytes).

Comment: @Lundin  Also, the example only makes sense when you move the two variables outside of the function. Do so, and then look at your AVR code again.

Comment: Sure, the scope of the variables is unclear by the question, as is the level of optimization that was used, if any. Why I voted to close the question - it cannot be answered without knowing the scope of the variables, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer.

Normally 16-bit arithmetics on 16-bit is faster, but It depends on compiler, optimization and architecture.

You have to at least compile it and check in the assembly.

In that particular case/example you may end with single 'mov' instruction in both cases because result can be predicted.